# How to replace a matching string with empty string in a JSON file?

Tags: json, shell

I have a file where each line is a JSON object:

```
{"index":{}}
{"msg_text":"yes","@timestamp":"2019-03-31T00:01:59.574Z","o_error":"INTERNAL_INVALID_MESSAGE","sender":"353830465174","account_id":"e15965cf-ffc1-40ae-94c4-b450ab190222","recipient":"49223","@version":1,"submission_ts":1553990519574000,"delivery_ts":1553990519574000}
{"index":{}}
{"msg_text":"yes","@timestamp":"2019-03-31T00:01:59.574Z","o_error":"INTERNAL_INVALID_MESSAGE","sender":"353830478555","account_id":"e15965cf-ffc1-40ae-94c4-b450ab190222","recipient":"49223","@version":1,"submission_ts":1553990519574000,"delivery_ts":1553990519575000}
{"index":{}}
```

I want to remove all the `delivery_ts` fields and values. So the following is what I want:

```
{"index":{}}
{"msg_text":"yes","@timestamp":"2019-03-31T00:01:59.574Z","o_error":"INTERNAL_INVALID_MESSAGE","sender":"353830465174","account_id":"e15965cf-ffc1-40ae-94c4-b450ab190222","recipient":"49223","@version":1,"submission_ts":1553990519574000}
{"index":{}}
{"msg_text":"yes","@timestamp":"2019-03-31T00:01:59.574Z","o_error":"INTERNAL_INVALID_MESSAGE","sender":"353830478555","account_id":"e15965cf-ffc1-40ae-94c4-b450ab190222","recipient":"49223","@version":1,"submission_ts":1553990519574000}
{"index":{}}
```

How can I do this using Linux commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing JSON is what [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) exists to do.

```
jq -c 'del(.delivery_ts)' <in.json >out.json
```

See this running against your stated input at https://jqplay.org/s/v1-J5cTMA-